# Options for realtime transcoding 1080p streams from file on beaglebone black

Tags: video-streaming, beagleboneblack

I have several 1080p video streams. I wanted to be able to stream any one of these streams to a browser. This requires that I transcode to a smaller resolution and to flv format or ogg/webm format. I tried this using vlc on the beagle bone black with the following command line.

```
cvlc 00080.MTS --sout "#transcode{vcodec=FLV1,acodec=mp3,vb=200,deinterlace,ab=32,width=720,height=480}:std{access=http,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=/stream.flv,caching=3000}"
```

This gives me the following error

```
[h264 @ 0xb547c3e0] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0xb547c3e0] Missing reference picture
```

I believe this is because the processor is too slow and incapable of handling 1080p. Because I tried the same thing with a 480p video and I get no such error.

My question is - Is there any other way I can transcode to a smaller resolution on the fly so it can be either streamed or viewed through HTML5 video. I tried pre transcoding all the streams but it took me 4 days and it still did not complete transcoding all the videos I had :) so that might not be an option. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the html5 player your only choices are [ogg and webm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) (or mp4, but that is not supported by vlc)

## Stream to WEBM

```
cvlc \
v4l2:///dev/video0 \
--sout '#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=1000}:std{access=http{mime=video/webm},mux=webm,dst=:8080/cam1}' \
-vvv
```

#### Notes:

180% - 250% CPU usage (on a 4core / 8 thread i7-4770)

## Stream to OGG

```
cvlc \
v4l2:///dev/video0 \
--sout '#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=2000}:std{access=http{mime=video/ogg},mux=ogg,dst=:8080/cam1}' \
-vvv
```

#### Notes

- 30% CPU usage
- Quality worse than webm (even when the bitrate is 2xWebM bitrate)

Comment: Thanks Matyas. Looks like the webm is not a possibility since I need to work on a low power processor. Ogg might be a possibility. But I have got hold of a raspberry pi board and I am going to try streaming with vlc compiled to use the GPU and decoder hardware accelerator and see if that can give me some performance improvement. [I will be following the steps in this tutorial](http://intensecode.blogspot.com/2013/10/tutorial-vlc-with-hardware-acceleration.html). I will post the results here when I do get done with it.

Comment: Cool :) Looking forward to see your results

Comment: If anyone is interested. I was able to transcode (still working on streaming ) 1080p MTS(h264 video) to 480p video using the hardware accelerators on raspberry pi using an open source project called omxtx. My plan is to mux it into an mp4 container and use that for the html5 video tag (most browsers support mp4 video tag). Anyway the decode-resize-encode path has a cpu utilization of only 20% which i think is pretty good so streaming 1080p videos seems to be a realistic option.

Comment: transcoding works ok. you can use also ffmpeg for that. The problem is that mp4 is not a format suitable for live streaming (only if you segment it). Mp4 puts metadata important for playback at the end of the file, which at a live stream does not exist. That is why in general it does not work.

Comment: So ffmpeg does not use use the hardware acceleration built in rpi and hence will be really slow. As for live streaming i have to play around a bit but there is fragmented mp4 and other such options that can be used. I am not sure if all browsers support it but from googling atleast saffari supports some form of streaming for mp4 files. Also 1 more experiment that i can try is i decode and scale using hardware And then encode the scaled YUV using ffmpeg on the cpu. I am not sure if i can meet the real time requirements with that but it is my backup if the mp4 thing does not work.

Comment: i know this is a year ago but any outcome? this is exactly what i am wanting to do on my pi

Comment: well, as it is outlined above the possibilities are: live transcoding via webm / ogg or almost live using segmented mp4 approach